# Check if the process in in RUNNING state or RUNNABLE state in Linux

Tags: process, linux-kernel, procfs

The state of any process can be found out by using multiple tools including reading from `/proc/[pid]/status` where

```sh
$ cat /proc/8976/status
Name:   redis-server
State:  R (Running)
Tgid:   8976
Pid:    8976
PPid:   8964
...
```

The `R` here typically denotes that the process is either in running or runnable state.
Can we somehow check using the existing `/proc` or `sysfs` or existing kernel tooling if the process is waiting to be scheduled upon the CPU in a runqueue or if the process is indeed running on the CPU?

I do understand that since Linux is preemptive, it can preempt after a time slice and maintain fairness amongst the processes which should not result in high runqueue latencies.

Comment: I remember when you couldn't do that because the process that was running rather than runnable was the process checking.

Comment: Thanks. Can you refer to the source for understanding it more.

Comment: At one time the number of CPUs that Linux knew how to use was one. https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/Historic/linux-0.01.tar.gz I wish I could answer your question though because with more than one processor, there really could be another running process.